# Java Recursion over 2 parameters and in two directions

Tags: java, recursion

I wish to recurse over two parameters simultaneously in a generic way. Here some explanation:

This is how the function calls should look like `Func(int a, int b)`:

- Call 0: `Func(0, 0)`
- Call 1: `Func(0, 1)`
- Call 1: `Func(1, 0)`
- Call 1: `Func(0, -1)`
- Call 1: `Func(-1, 0)`

How would I implement this in code, ensuring the following statements:

- All possible combinations of `a INRANGE (-INF, INF)` and `b INRANGE (-INF, INF)` are considered.
- There is no overhead, with that I mean that the same function is not used several times in the recursion.

I later want to expand it to do the same thing over 7 parameters.

Regards.

Comment: ps. This is a followup from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18058711/java-recursion-over-multiple-parameters-in-two-directions-up-down , my aim is that this post is way more concise. Maybe the old post should be closed?

Comment: If the old question will have no future value to anyone and doesn't have an upvoted answer it can and should be deleted (you should be able to delete it yourself).

Comment: The more generic you make the solution the slower it will be.  Is performance a consideration.  btw:  a generic search over 7 parameters for 10 values will take 100,000 times longer than it will for 2 parameters. For 1000 values it will take a billion trillion times longer and might not be practical any more.

Comment: @Dukeling Question deletions like these are somewhat controversial as they can lead to question bans when done in large numbers.

Comment: You may **spiral on a X,Y grid** starting from (0, 0) but that need not be done recursively.

Comment: @JoopEggen Actually it not need to use recursion. So I am interested in that approach definately.

Comment: @hexafraction So don't do it in large numbers then? I'm not 100% sure how the banning works, but I suspect it's more about having your questions deleted (as opposed to deleting them oneself), or excessive downvotes, regardless of deletions. Generally it shouldn't be something to worry about if you follow [the check-list](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my take on the spiral approach:

```
// this is your function
static void func(int x, int y)
{
  System.out.println("x = "+x+", y = "+y);
}

// this calls func for all possible combinations of signs of the variables in arr
static void allPossibleSigns(int pos, Integer... arr)
{
  if (pos == arr.length)
  {
     func(arr[0], arr[1]); // not really generic
  }
  else
  {
     allPossibleSigns(pos+1, arr);
     arr[pos] = -arr[pos];
     if (arr[pos] != 0)
        allPossibleSigns(pos+1, arr);
  }
}

static void caller()
{
  for (int t = 0; t < MAX; t++)
  for (int x = 0; x <= t; x++)
  {
     int y = (t-x);
     allPossibleSigns(0, x, y);
  }
}
```

If you want something more generic than `func(arr[0], arr[1]);`, you can replace it with:

```
Method[] methods = NewMain.class.getMethods();
for (Method m: methods)
{
   if (m.getName().equals("func"))
      m.invoke(null, arr);
}
```

and add some error checking. I used `Integer...` instead of `int...` in `printAllPossibleSigns` because of this approach (the above doesn't work for `int...`). This assumes you only have one function called `func`. If this is not the case, you'll have to add some additional checks.

For `MAX` = 4, it prints:

```
x = 0, y = 0
x = 0, y = 1
x = 0, y = -1
x = 1, y = 0
x = -1, y = 0
x = 0, y = 2
x = 0, y = -2
x = 1, y = 1
x = 1, y = -1
x = -1, y = -1
x = -1, y = 1
x = 2, y = 0
x = -2, y = 0
x = 0, y = 3
x = 0, y = -3
x = 1, y = 2
x = 1, y = -2
x = -1, y = -2
x = -1, y = 2
x = 2, y = 1
x = 2, y = -1
x = -2, y = -1
x = -2, y = 1
x = 3, y = 0
x = -3, y = 0
```

How this will be extended to 3 variable may not entirely be clear, so here's `caller` for 3 variables:

```
static void caller()
{
  for (int t = 0; t < MAX; t++)
  for (int x = 0; x <= t; x++)
  for (int y = 0; y <= (t-x); y++)
  {
     int z = (t-x-y);
     printAllPossibleSigns(0, x, y, z);
  }
}
```

And that's about all you have to change, along with your function, obviously, and `func(arr[0], arr[1]);` if you didn't choose the generic approach.

Comment: I am kind of understand it, except that `if (pos == arr.length)` seems a bit like magic to me.

Comment: That's the deepest step of our recursive function, when we reached the end of the array. So the function generates all combinations of signs from the start of the array until the end. At the end, we should simply call the function. I hope that clears it up a bit, I don't think I can explain it much better.

Answer (score 1):

I propose a spiral, non-recursively easiest.
For ease of reading the move is selected again in every step.

```
int x = 0;
int y = 0;
for (int t = 0; t < 100; ++t) {
    func(x, y);
    if (x <= 0 && y == 0) { // Widen spiral.
        --x;
        ++y; // So next condition takes next.
    } else if (x < 0 && y >= 0) { // Left, upper quadrant.
        ++x;
        ++y;
    } else if (x >= 0 && y > 0) { // Right, upper.
        ++x;
        --y;
    } else if (x >= 0 && y <= 0) { // Right, lower.
        --x;
        --y;
    } else if (x < 0 && y < 0) { // Left, lower.
        --x;
        ++y;
    } else {
        throw new IllegalStateException("x = " + x + ", y = " + y);
    }
}
```

*I did not try the code! Check the conditions.*

Comment: I am struggling in how to use this for `nD` though. 3D would be a hell to understand and 7D like not ever going to be possible. Spiraling on 7 dimensions is though very needed for the optimal solution for my application.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe some knowledge of **combinatorics** would help here. To me this looks like you have a set of elements from -N to to +N. Now you want to call a function with for each **variation** of length == 7 those elements.

**Such a range may be really big. Depending on the cost of the operation you want to call this might take longer than you live.**

I would write an `Iterator` which delivers a new variation of the elements (which are your function parameters) on each call of next().

The implementation of such an iterator could you `BigInteger`, if you need big numbers. You could use an `Array` or `List` and change it's elements on each iteration. If you search for combinatorial algorithms or permutation / variation algorithms you might find details and maybe even implementations.

Another (similar) way (with more overhead, I think) would be to use just one number (e.g. a BigInteger) to mark the current variation. On each iteration you add 1 to this variation index number.

To get your parameters from this number you must perform a base transformation on this variation index. The base will be the number of elements in your elements set. The resulting number's digits each have the range of 0 to the number of elements -1. From this you can use each digit to get the parameters for your function call from the list of elements.

I did than some time ago and it works fine. Can't promise than I can find it.

Answer (score 0):

***For n dimensions:***

Below I use *positive* numbers for coordinates. For every positive (greater 0) coordinate in a solution making the coordinate negative also is a solution (almost factor 2^n solutions more). *(Using positive numbers simplifies the reading of a solution.)*

This is a solutions for a coordinate vector of dimension n. The coordinates are chosen with ever growing "radius" = sum of coordinates.

```
static void func(int[] x) {
    System.out.printf("%s%n", Arrays.toString(x));
}

/**
 * Call many funcs with several coordinates.
 * @param x n-dimensional coordinates.
 * @param fromI starting index for variable coordinates.
 * @param r radius, equal to the sum of x[>= fromIndex].
 * @param t downward counter limiting the number of calls.
 * @return new value of t.
 */
static int callFuncsForRadius(int[] x, int fromIndex, int r, int t) {
    if (t <= 0) {
        return t;
    }
    if (fromIndex >= x.length) { // Nothing more to vary.
        if (r == 0) { // Read radius sum.
            func(x);
            --t;
        }
        return t;
    }
    for (int rNext = r; rNext >= 0; --rNext) {
        x[fromIndex] = rNext;
        t = callFuncsForRadius(x, fromIndex + 1, r - rNext, t);
        if (t <= 0) {
            break;
        }
    }
    return t;
}

static int callFuncs(int[] x, int t) {
    int r = 0;
    while (t > 0) {
        t = callFuncsForRadius(x, 0, r, t);
        ++r;
    }
    return t;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int n = 3;
    int[] x = new int[n];
    int t = 10; // N^n, where N = 2^31.
    callFuncs(x, t);
}
```