# Spiralling in nD

Tags: java, dimensions, spiral

I would like to implement the Spiral pattern in n-dimensions.

A great answer for 2D, which I have received is on this question: [Java Recursion over 2 parameters and in two directions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18059220/java-recursion-over-2-parameters-and-in-two-directions) , the answer is not tested though, but you will get the idea.

However as I want to use it in 7 dimensions, it seemed to me that it was more simple to implement this in nD.

The only code I have to show is the code from Joop Eggen on my thread, unfortunately I cannot post my own code for nD (let alone 3D), as it would be simply too hard. Neither have I found anything on Google on this.

Could anyone please help me out in general documentation, code or what ever that helps me?

I see that in 2D it uses quadrants, so I figured that there should be a similar pattern for that in 3D, but what about nD?

Regards.